# How to start jar file with specified parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, jvm

I have some old springboot applications developed from

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

They run well in my server but one day I find a strange problem:
They seems not support the JVM standard parameter command such as
`-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`
It can only use `--spring.profiles.active=dev` to start the application.
Using `-Xms256M -Xmx256M -Xmn200M` to specify the memory of the application will also make nonsense.

and the build plugin was

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Because my server has the latest maven version at 3.8+, my new applications from spring-boot-starter-parent `2.3.2.RELEASE` also meet this situation but solved by upgrade the plugin version.

So I think there maybe some problem with the version of maven, so I changed the plugin's version into the latest ones like below,and my applications developed from spring-boot-starter-parent `2.3.2.RELEASE` will work properly,but those from `1.5.8.RELEASE` still crashed.

````
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>```

I'm strongly doubt it is the problem of maven version. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Could any one help me about this? Thanks alot !
````

Answer (score 0):

Ah...the problem solved.

I misunderstood the command.

by using `java -jar filename.jar`

the specified parameter must be in front of `filename.jar`

just like `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev filename.jar`

otherwise you use `java -jar filename.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev`

both way will work.

Comment: The parameter does not belong between `-jar` and the actual jar file name.